# How to fix ‘An unhandled exception IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF In ASP.NET MVC'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm working on My ASP.NET MVC Project (ComputerOwnersDb) and use Code-First-Migration Approach. In spite of IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON, from Unit View (Add.cshtml), I faced with exception:

> 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Units' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.'

but when i try to insert same data with create a migration and write sql ("INSERT INTO Units VALUES 'Medical Records','Johns Smith'"),everything is fine and record successfully added to Db.
anybody can help?

```
public class Unit
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        public string Manager { get; set; }
    }
```

Unit (Controller Code):

```
public class UnitController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UnitController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }


    // GET: Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var unitList = _context.Units.ToList();
        return View(unitList);
    }

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var newUnit = new Unit();
        return View(newUnit);
    }
    public ActionResult Save(Unit unit)
    {
        unit.Id = 0;
        _context.Units.Add(unit);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Unit");
    }
}

Unit (Add's View Code):

    @model ComputerOwnersDb.Models.Unit
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Add";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Add New Unit</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Unit"))
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UnitName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Manager)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Manager, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `id` is an `INT IDENTITY` column in the SQL Server table, you need to add an annotation to your `Id` column in the model class:

```
public class Unit
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
}
```

This `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` tells EF that SQL Server will take care of creating the value for `Id`, and EF will create an  `INSERT` statement that does **not** explicitly try to insert a value into `Id` (but instead it lets SQL Server handle that task).

Now, once you save the new data, SQL Server will create a new value for `Id` and EF will show that `Id` value after the call to `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: ohhhh man!!! it's a perfectly correct answer.
I added this annotation and After that, exception message is gone forever.
you’re awesome and you made my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult Save(Unit unit)
 {
     unit.Id = 0;
     _context.Units.Add(unit);
     _context.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index","Unit");
 }
```

Don't explicitly assign an `Id` to the object. Add an object to the context without `Id`. The database will create the `Id` for you upon insert, and Entity Framework will catch and return this `Id`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,but when I added or deleted this code ('unit.Id = 0;'), i've got same result :(